# Coq - Proving condition about elements of sequence in Ssreflect

Tags: coq, ssreflect

I have a goal that looks like this:

```
x \in [seq (f v j) | j <- enum 'I_m & P v j] -> 0 < x
```

In the above, `f` is a definition generating a solution of an inequality depending on `v, j` and `P v j` is a predicate restricting j to indices which satisfy another inequality.

I have already proven that `Goal : P v j -> (f v j > 0)`, but how can I use this to prove that it holds for any `x` in the sequence? I have found just a few relevant lemmas like `nthP` which introduce sequence manipulation, which I'm very unfamiliar with.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the `mapP` lemma (that characterizes `mem`bership wrt `map`):

```
Lemma U m (P : rel 'I_m) f v x (hp : forall j, P v j -> f v j > 0) :
  x \in [seq f v j | j <- enum 'I_m & P v j] -> 0 < x.
Proof. by case/mapP=> [y]; rewrite mem_filter; case/andP=> /hp ? _ ->. Qed.
```